# JSON+jq - if a key's value matches regex, then create a new key-value pair of existing key-value by formatting date

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json file.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "startdate": "2022-10-14 12:05:49",
      "name": "hello1",
      "run_status_index": 29
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "startdate": "2022-10-14 11:45:36",
      "name": "hello2",
      "run_status_index": 95
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, if the name is `hello1`, then I want to add 18hours to the startdate and create a new key called `"endate".` For `hello2`, I want to add 24hours to startdate and create `"endate"`.

So, the output would be...

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "startdate": "2022-10-14 12:05:49",
      "endate": "2022-10-15 06:05:49",
      "name": "hello1",
      "run_status_index": 29
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "startdate": "2022-10-14 11:45:36",
      "endate": "2022-10-15 11:45:36",
      "name": "hello2",
      "run_status_index": 95
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following based on my searches but I cannot wrap my head around the if statements.

`jq 'def n: if .data == "" then null else . end; .endate = ((.startdate|n) // "")'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```bash
.data[] |= (
  (.name | if test("hello1") then 18 else 24 end) as $add
  | .enddate = (
      .startdate | strptime("%F %T") | .[3] += $add | mktime | strftime("%F %T")
    )
)
```

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "startdate": "2022-10-14 12:05:49",
      "name": "hello1",
      "run_status_index": 29,
      "enddate": "2022-10-15 06:05:49"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "startdate": "2022-10-14 11:45:36",
      "name": "hello2",
      "run_status_index": 95,
      "enddate": "2022-10-15 11:45:36"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/3mw64HkciLE)

Note: `test` implements a regex match. For a simple string comparison `.name == "hello1"` would suffice.

Comment: Thank you very much. What if I have more than 2 name conditions? Any pointers please? I am just starting with jq and any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: @jsmith From the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#if-then-else): "More cases can be added to an if using `elif A then B` syntax."

Comment: @jsmith Using `elif` as well as using `def` in another example: `def n: .name | if test("hello1") then 18 elif test("hello2") then 24 else 0 end; .data[] |= (n as $n | .enddate = (.startdate | strptime("%F %T") | .[3] += $n | mktime | strftime("%F %T")))` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/OablcQmu2co)